# How does one send S-RET to Emacs in a terminal?

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, emacs23, org-mode

In `org-mode`, pressing `M-S-RET` (meta-shift-return) will create a new `TODO` on a new line. This key sequence sends `M-RET` to emacs through my terminal. I've checked this with `C-h c ESC-S-RET`, which returns `M-RET is undefined` in the mini-buffer.

I'm using Snow Leopard with Emacs 23.2.1 running in Terminal.app. There is no option to define a `RET` sequence in the terminal keyboard preferences.

Any idea what's causing the missing `SHIFT`? Workarounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get Emacs to pretend that it got `S-RET` with `C-x @ S RET` (note uppercase `S`).

This also works for adding control, meta, alt, hyper or super modifiers; type `C-x @ C-h` for the list of bindings.  The [Modifier Keys section in the Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html) mentions this as well.

Comment: This answer provides a hack: map the terminal's (iTerm's, more specifically) M/S-RET to what Emacs would process as as M/S-RET https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62538/29629

Answer (score 5):

In general, lots of keystrokes are simply impossible to send via a terminal, since terminals emulate an old protocol that only allowed 256 separate keys (or maybe only 128).

Chances are, when you press S-RET, Terminal.app does *exactly* the same thing as if you'd pressed RET.  Thus Emacs has no way to distinguish those two cases.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case. I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if anyone out there knows which terminal I should emulate to get `S-RET`. It may not be possible. Currently, terminal reports itself as `xterm-color`, but I can change this in the config options. Don't know if it would solve anything though.

Answer (score 3):

Cross-linking to other Q&As:

If you are using an xterm, then the `modifyOtherKeys` option may facilitate that binding. See the following for details:

[Send "C-(" to Emacs in VT100/xterm terminal (Mac OS X's Terminal)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337837/send-c-to-emacs-in-vt100-xterm-terminal-mac-os-xs-terminal)

I suspect Emacs recognises those codes by default, but if not then also see `input-decode-map` as described here: [Binding M-<up> / M-<down> in Emacs 23.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351044/binding-m-up-m-down-in-emacs-23-1-1/4360658#4360658)

Answer (score 2):

See explanation and alternative shortcuts for TTY [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-keys.html#TTY-keys).

Some of these have worked for me in a terminal in Ubuntu Linux (both locally and over SSH), but not all of them seem to work. For example, the alternative provided for `S-RET` (which I expected to run `org-table-copy-down`) instead seems to run `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` for some reason. However, I have found the list of alternatives useful, particularly those with the `M-` prefix. For example `ESC UP` for `M-UP` to move text around in tables.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a lot of extra key presses, it turns out that `org-mode` has an alternative:

`C-c C-x <shift> m`

i.e. `C-c C-x M`

https://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-Keys.html#TTY-keys