# Search and replace inside a rectangle in emacs

Tags: search, emacs, replace

Is it possible to perform a `replace-string` operation inside of a rectangular region in emacs? If so, how?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you enable CUA selection mode:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `cua-selection-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or permanently in your init file:

```
(cua-selection-mode 1)
```

You can then use its advanced rectangle editing facilities.

(or if you're a `cua-mode` user, then you don't need to do that.)

- <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to mark a corner.
- Move point to opposite corner.
- <kbd>M-r</kbd> to do a *regexp* replace within the marked rectangle.
- <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to unmark/exit rectangle editing.

For documentation, look for the "CUA rectangle support" heading in the commentary in <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `cua-base` <kbd>RET</kbd>

If you don't want to use the cua rectangle facilities for some reason (perhaps if you really need `replace-string` specifically), a custom function using `apply-on-rectangle` would be pretty simply to put together.

**Edit**: Actually, slightly more complex than I had expected, but most of the code is the interactive spec and the support for the 'delimited' prefix argument behaviour (both based on `replace-string`).

**Edit 2**: I decided this was worth doing in a more fully-featured manner:

The following provides <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>M-%</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>C-M-%</kbd>, which (hopefully) act the way you would expect.

```el
(require 'rect)

(defun my-search-replace-in-rectangle
  (start end search-pattern replacement search-function literal)
  "Replace all instances of SEARCH-PATTERN (as found by SEARCH-FUNCTION)
with REPLACEMENT, in each line of the rectangle established by the START
and END buffer positions.

SEARCH-FUNCTION should take the same BOUND and NOERROR arguments as
`search-forward' and `re-search-forward'.

The LITERAL argument is passed to `replace-match' during replacement.

If `case-replace' is nil, do not alter case of replacement text."
  (apply-on-rectangle
   (lambda (start-col end-col search-function search-pattern replacement)
     (move-to-column start-col)
     (let ((bound (min (+ (point) (- end-col start-col))
                       (line-end-position)))
           (fixedcase (not case-replace)))
       (while (funcall search-function search-pattern bound t)
         (replace-match replacement fixedcase literal))))
   start end search-function search-pattern replacement))

(defun my-replace-regexp-rectangle-read-args (regexp-flag)
  "Interactively read arguments for `my-replace-regexp-rectangle'
or `my-replace-string-rectangle' (depending upon REGEXP-FLAG)."
  (let ((args (query-replace-read-args
               (concat "Replace"
                       (if current-prefix-arg " word" "")
                       (if regexp-flag " regexp" " string"))
               regexp-flag)))
    (list (region-beginning) (region-end)
          (nth 0 args) (nth 1 args) (nth 2 args))))

(defun my-replace-regexp-rectangle
  (start end regexp to-string &optional delimited)
  "Perform a regexp search and replace on each line of a rectangle
established by START and END (interactively, the marked region),
similar to `replace-regexp'.

Optional arg DELIMITED (prefix arg if interactive), if non-nil, means
replace only matches surrounded by word boundaries.

If `case-replace' is nil, do not alter case of replacement text."
  (interactive (my-replace-regexp-rectangle-read-args t))
  (when delimited
    (setq regexp (concat "\\b" regexp "\\b")))
  (my-search-replace-in-rectangle
   start end regexp to-string 're-search-forward nil))

(defun my-replace-string-rectangle
  (start end from-string to-string &optional delimited)
  "Perform a string search and replace on each line of a rectangle
established by START and END (interactively, the marked region),
similar to `replace-string'.

Optional arg DELIMITED (prefix arg if interactive), if non-nil, means
replace only matches surrounded by word boundaries.

If `case-replace' is nil, do not alter case of replacement text."
  (interactive (my-replace-regexp-rectangle-read-args nil))
  (let ((search-function 'search-forward))
    (when delimited
      (setq search-function 're-search-forward
            from-string (concat "\\b" (regexp-quote from-string) "\\b")))
    (my-search-replace-in-rectangle
     start end from-string to-string search-function t)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r M-%") 'my-replace-string-rectangle)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r C-M-%") 'my-replace-regexp-rectangle)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it seems I can only mark a corner with `C-RET` in the emacs GUI, not in terminal mode.

Comment: That'll be due to your terminal not sending that sequence. You may find an xterm more successful (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337837/send-c-to-emacs-in-vt100-xterm-terminal-mac-os-xs-terminal). I've also updated my answer with more fully-featured code for the non-CUA approach.

Comment: Feature request: search the rectangle. I have a huge column and I need to check does it have anything else but `DPP`. I use some complex regexp -- and if the column is really big -- I get regexp stack overflow.

Comment: Just a note for others who might be confused like me - M-r is bound to cua-replace-in-rectangle only when a selected rectangle is active.

Comment: Thank you for the lisp, it is just working out of the box!

Answer (score 6):

In recent Emacs (e.g. Emacs 25) you can do this out of the box using `M-%` (`query-replace`) or `C-M-%` (`query-replace-regexp`).

Use `M-x rectangle-mark-mode` to create the rectangular region.  Use `C-x C-x` if necessary, to put point before mark.  Then just query-replace.

They didn't, however, make the same change in Emacs 25 for `replace-string`.  You can do that, if you like, just by adding argument `region-noncontiguous-p` the same way it's done in `query-replace`.  The code is simple:

```el
(defun replace-string (from-string to-string &optional delimited start end backward
                       region-noncontiguous-p)
  "..."
  (declare (interactive-only
            "use `search-forward' and `replace-match' instead."))
  (interactive
   (let ((common
          (query-replace-read-args
           (concat "Replace"
                   (if current-prefix-arg
                       (if (eq current-prefix-arg '-) " backward" " word")
                     "")
                   " string"
                   (if (use-region-p) " in region" ""))
           nil)))
     (list (nth 0 common) (nth 1 common) (nth 2 common)
           (if (use-region-p) (region-beginning))
           (if (use-region-p) (region-end))
           (nth 3 common)
           (if (use-region-p) (region-noncontiguous-p)))))
  (perform-replace
    from-string to-string nil nil delimited nil nil start end backward region-noncontiguous-p))
```

Alternatively, you can just download library [`replace+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/replace%2b.el) and use the version of `replace-string` from there.  It does what you want.

FWIW, I've just filed Emacs [bug#27897](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=27897) to get this feature added to `replace-string` and several other commands in the same library, `replace.el`.

Comment: There is also an anzu bug (which might be replacing your version of `query-replace`) related to this: https://github.com/syohex/emacs-anzu/issues/69

Answer (score 2):

For evil users, you can use my package [evil-visual-replace](https://github.com/troyp/evil-visual-replace) to get `query-replace` and `replace-regexp` inside evil visual blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in CUA mode, you can use cua-replace-in-rectangle bound to 'M-r'.

Comment: But this only replaces first occurrence of the thing (default vim replace-regexp behavior).