# howto send emacs control-quote (C-') via terminal (iTerm2)

Tags: macos, emacs24, iterm2

I have seen this answer for the case of xterm 
[Send "C-(" to Emacs in VT100/xterm terminal (Mac OS X's Terminal)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337837/send-c-to-emacs-in-vt100-xterm-terminal-mac-os-xs-terminal)

Yet, how would i represent the conrol key in <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>char</kbd> combinations (like emacs C-') while sending escape-sequences or hex-codes via iTerm2 ?

Experimenting in accord with the link above, I can send <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>&</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>(</kbd> BUT NOT <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd> . Why?

```
^[[27;6;38~ yields C-&    as expected
^[[27;6;39~ yields ~      only tilde 
^[[27;6;40~ yields C-(    as expected
```

Comment: Finally this works:

    ^[[27;5;39~ yields C-'

Comment: what do you write in iterm2 ? Action: send Hex code and put `^[[27;5;39~` ?

Comment: No, i didn't do anything in this case. iTerm2 appears just sends it like this.

Comment: You can send <CTRL> key to emacs by giving C-x @ c. So, please try C-x @ c ' instead of C-', it might work.