# How to modify aquamacs keyboard shortcuts

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, aquamacs

I'd like to redefine some of the default aquamacs shortcuts.

I've tried putting this in my preferences.el file:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "A-l"))
(global-set-key (kbd "A-l") 'forward char)
```

but it doesn't change the behavior of CMD-l

Comment: `"A-l"` might be wrong. Try to find out what string to use for the `kbd` function using answers/comments from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351044/binding-m-up-m-down-in-emacs-23-1-1 question.

Answer (score 1):

check the key descriptor as JF Sebastian said. But there is another typo in what you have written, it should be something like:

```
(global-set-key [(meta l)] 'forward-char)
```

(I am using meta, but by default aquamacs doesn't seem to have command has meta, not sure what it is)

You can check to what the key is mapped by typing:

```
c-h c
```

and then the key combination you want to check. It will tell you in the minibuffer. You can thus check if your binding worked fine without restarting etc.